# Ignore errors on Data Source in SSIS

Tags: ssis, datasource

I have 3 million rows customers.csv file. When I import it in SQL 2008, I am getting a data source step in a data flow.  "[Source - Customers_csv [1]] Error: The column delimiter for column "CCode" was not found." CCode is the last column in the file.

The error is on data row 82824. I can't open this 2GB file to look what is going on.

How could I just ignore this error?

ob

Comment: Get the demo version of Textpad - http://www.textpad.com/ - which should enable you to open your source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting "Ignore failure" on both errors and truncation. See:

http://www.safnet.com/writing/tech/archives/2007/08/ignoring_ssis_d.html

Comment: The error happens on a datasource "Customers_csv" step, so I can't "Ignore failure" on both errors and truncation

OB

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.  Here's the link that works, but the images on the page are still broken. http://www.safnet.com/writing/tech/2007/08/ignoring-ssis-d.html

Answer (score 0):

I set redirect to error output, added the data viewer to it and was able to look at the erroneous row. The row had text qualifiers and column delimiters messed up.